# Is the Gmail activity log still missing activesync?

Tags: audit, email

Is the Gmail activity log still missing activesync as described in this [blog post](http://securityevaluators.com/content/blog/?page=2009-12-17_Gmail_activity_log)?
As it is "*someone with my credentials could be reading and sending [email] messages with my account*" without that access being reported via the log.

Comment: Lance - can you add some more context to your question.

Comment: I suppose the question is about whether the mentioned bug in the blog post has been fixed or not. The wording could be improved.

Comment: To be fair, can you compare this to any other free online email services that offer https security and auditing of access to your email account?

Comment: Of course not, but this subtle bug effectively disables the auditing functionality and hence leads to a false sense of security, which (in some cases) may be worse than not having auditing. Anyway I reported it a while ago but I guess they already know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some testing, using my windows mobile phone & activesync. The Activity Log, indeed does not log anything, only when just *receiving* mails. But whenever you do some change that can lead to an update operation, then it logs this attempt.

Say for example I initiate a sync operation and 10 messages are downloaded on my mobile as soon as the activesync finishes - 7 I have already read on my PC and 3 new unread. 
This sync operation **does not** get logged in the Activity Monitor.

If I read one of the already read mails, and then sync, again it is not logged.

But I read one of the unread mails, and thus change its state, the next sync operation **is logged** (with name "Mobile"). The same happens if I send a mail - the sync gets logged.

So to sum up, a clever attacker that has stolen credentials **can** read all the emails of a person, without being noticed, by manipulating the active sync queries so no updates are sent, or by changing the state of the mails back to unread after reading them.

Comment: OMG! security hole? :P

Comment: Seems like plausibly reasonable behavior -- it has the benefit of avoiding spamming the activity logs.

Comment: If you consider that POP or IMAP accesses get logged, then it is a 'bug'.